# Hardware Networking

Tags: networking, hardware

I'm setting a  static on my P.C. such as
10.1.18.77
255.255.255.0
10.1.18.1
10.1.18.1

My Hardware on my network is 192.168.200.100-200

I would like to enter 192.168.200.100 in my browser and see my hardware. login and password.  Having issues in the network trying to set this up.

In windows i can enter 192.168.200.77 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.200.1 in the advanced and everything works

New at Linux.  any help will be greatfull.  Since I don't want to run windows anymore.

Comment: Loaded Mint also and have the same issues.

Comment: I also would like the have ideal's about remote connections.  Would like to use Mint but splashtop doesn't work with Mint just Ubuntu.  Any body have link to remote pc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a difference in the 2 OSs, chromium is a similar browser to chrome so whatever you can do in chrome you can do in chromium, all you do is type the same IP in the adress bar and you will be redirected out to the login modal. you can also do this using terminal and if that is what you would like to know how to do then edit your question and i'll see if i can help.

Check the application NetworkAdmin for ubuntu it is similar to network and sharing center. Find out more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkAdmin

also check, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

i would try to explain a personalized solution as well if you could actually explain your issue a little better. I didn't quite understand the last part of your question because i use 3rd party applications for what you are using windows tools to do

Comment: My Network Static is 10.1.18.77  Subnet 255.255.255.0 G/W 10.1.18.1 DND 10.1.18.1  i'm able to browse the network.   My Hardware address is 192.168.200.100 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.200.1 when I type the ip in my browser it doesn't work .

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I windows i click on advanced and type 192.168.200.1 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.200.1 and it's works

Comment: advanced what and where?

Comment: Go to Network Sharing  /  change adapter setting / left click on local area connections / click on properties / Click on TCP/ipv4 /  Click on Properities /  Click on advanced /  click on add   192.168.200.17, 255.255.255.0  / save  ....     17 is just a number not used if you hardware is on 192.168.200.100 then you will get login and password  fileld's  this way to keep your hardware away from the 254 addresses your router is sending out.

Comment: try the application NetworkAdmin it is similar to the network and sharing settings in windows, find out more here:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkAdmin

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered from your comments your static IP address is 10.1.18.77 subnetmask is 255.255.255.0, gateway is 10.1.18.1 and dns is 10.1.18.1

You are trying to access resources from a system with ip address 192.168.200.100 having a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 where the gateway is 192.168.200.1

Now you want to temporarily change the ip address of your machine to be in the same network as your resource network, you choose 192.168.200.17 as it is not assigned to any device.

Assuming you are using the configuration for eth0, incase you have a different interface name please substitute it as needed.

For temporary network configuration type the following commands in terminal these commands allow you to configure settings which take effect immediately, however they are not persistent and will be lost after a reboot.

`sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.200.17 netmask 255.255.255.0`

`sudo route add default gw 192.168.200.1 eth0`

f you require DNS for your temporary network configuration, you can add DNS server IP addresses in the file /etc/resolv.conf, though editing this file is not usually recommended.

`nameserver 192.168.200.17`

If you no longer need this configuration and wish to purge all IP configuration from this interface

`sudo ip addr flush eth0`

Please try this and let me know by adding a comment with @Ads so I can troubleshoot the problem, sorry for getting confused earlier.